# Почему не обрабатывается вывод через sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, liquibase

Пытаюсь скрыть первые 19 строк вывод программы (liquibase cli), однако вывод никаким образом не меняется. Подскажите, возможно ли, что блокируется pipe или какие другие штуки?

Моя задача скрыть приветствие и логотип.

Стандартный вывод:

```
$ ./liquibase
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 10:13:18 (version 4.5.0 #52 built at 2021-09-27 16:19+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.5.0
Liquibase Community 4.5.0 by Datical
Missing required subcommand
```

**Перенаправление через sed**:

```
$ ./liquibase | sed '1,19d'
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 10:07:19 (version 4.5.0 #52 built at 2021-09-27 16:19+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.5.0
Liquibase Community 4.5.0 by Datical
Missing required subcommand
Usage: liquibase [GLOBAL OPTIONS] [COMMAND] [COMMAND OPTIONS]
Command-specific help: "liquibase <command-name> --help"
```

`./liquibase > /dev/null` не работает

`./liquibase &> /dev/null` работает

P.S. скорее всего что-то делаю не так

Comment: Пробовал `liquebase 2>&1 | ...`? Если сработает, то `sed` не нужен вообще.

Comment: @0andriy спасибо, получилось убрать логотип `liquibase 2>&1 | sed '1,19d'` Не понял, почему sed будет не нужен вообще? Мне нужно удалить только первые 19 строк вывода.

Comment: @Zempik `liquebase 2>/dev/null` -уберет печать stderr

Comment: Перенаправьте `2>&1`, тогда `sed` увидит выводимые символы

Comment: проблема решена. спасибо за помощь!